# How to correctly calculate the the number of bytes of a node.js stream that have been processed?

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a stream I'm sending over the wire and takes a bit of time to fully send, so I want to display how far along it is on the fly. I know you can listen on the 'data' event for streams, but in newer versions of node, it also puts the stream into "flowing mode". I want to make sure i'm doing this correctly.

Currently I have the following stuff:

```
deploymentPackageStream.pause() // to prevent it from entering "flowing mode"
var bytesSent = 0
deploymentPackageStream.on('data', function(data) {
    bytesSent+=data.length
    process.stdout.write('\r                   ')
    process.stdout.write('\r'+(bytesSent/1000)+'kb sent')
})
deploymentPackageStream.resume()

// copy over the deployment package
execute(conn, 'cat > deploymentPackage.sh', deploymentPackageStream).wait()
```

This gives me the right bytesSent output, but the resulting package seems to be missing some data off the front. If I put the 'resume' line after executing the copy line (the last line), it doesn't copy anything. If I don't resume, it also doesn't copy anything. What's going on and how do I do this properly without disrupting the stream and without entering flowing mode (I want back pressure)?

I should mention, i'm still using node v0.10.x

Comment: Flowing mode lets you read data as in comes in, and paused mode requires you to explicitly call `stream.read()` to get data. Isn't flowing mode what you want?

Comment: @gregnr Flowing mode means there's no backpressure right? The last line there sends the stream over the network, and I want backpressure for that. What i really want is for that last line to request data (via stream.read() somewhere), and for *both* that copying code *and* the bytes-sent-printing code to get the data (via the event for the bytes-sent stuff and via stream.read() for the last line that sends it over the network).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I made something that essentially is a passthrough, but calls a callback with data as it comes in:

```
// creates a stream that can view all the data in a stream and passes the data through
// parameters:
    // stream - the stream to peek at
    // callback - called when there's data sent from the passed stream
var StreamPeeker = exports.StreamPeeker = function(stream, callback) {
    Readable.call(this)
    this.stream = stream

    stream.on('readable', function() {
        var data = stream.read()
        if(data !== null) {
            if(!this.push(data)) stream.pause()
            callback(data)
        }
    }.bind(this))

    stream.on('end', function() {
        this.push(null)
    }.bind(this))
}
util.inherits(StreamPeeker, Readable)
StreamPeeker.prototype._read = function() {
    this.stream.resume()
}
```

If I understand streams properly, this should appropriately handle backpressure.

Using this, I can just count up data.length in the callback like this:

```
var peeker = new StreamPeeker(stream, function(data) {
   // use data.length
})
peeker.pipe(destination)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working right - backpressure doesn't seem to be applied. It runs through the data, but on the other end, it can take a few minutes to actually see the data come through. Effing streams